# How to link files within other directories?

Tags: kernel-module, kbuild

I have a project that is big enough to benefit from having its files classified by directory. I'm trying to build **one** kernel module out of all of them.

The [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt) states the following:

```
--- 3.6 Descending down in directories

A Makefile is only responsible for building objects in its own
directory. Files in subdirectories should be taken care of by
Makefiles in these subdirs. The build system will automatically
invoke make recursively in subdirectories, provided you let it know of
them.

To do so, obj-y and obj-m are used.
ext2 lives in a separate directory, and the Makefile present in fs/
tells kbuild to descend down using the following assignment.

Example:
    #fs/Makefile
    obj-$(CONFIG_EXT2_FS) += ext2/

If CONFIG_EXT2_FS is set to either 'y' (built-in) or 'm' (modular)
the corresponding obj- variable will be set, and kbuild will descend
down in the ext2 directory.
```

However, this seems to be different from what I need. What comes out of this is two independent `.ko` files; one in each directory, each an amalgamation of the object files in its own directory.

This is my project (simplified):

```
root directory
 |
 +--- Makefile
 |
 +--- foo.c
 |
 +--- subdir
       |
       +--- Makefile
       |
       +--- bar.c
```

I would think that ending up with something like this would be reasonable:

```
root directory
 |
 +--- Makefile
 |
 +--- foo.c
 |
 +--- foo.o (containing foo.c's stuff)
 |
 +--- subdir
 |     |
 |     +--- Makefile
 |     |
 |     +--- bar.c
 |     |
 |     +--- bar.o (containing bar.c's stuff)
 |
 +--- kernel-module.ko (containing foo.o and subdir/bar.o)
```

What I really end up with is this:

```
root directory
 |
 +--- Makefile
 |
 +--- foo.c
 |
 +--- foo.o (containing foo.c's stuff)
 |
 +--- subdir
 |     |
 |     +--- Makefile
 |     |
 |     +--- bar.c
 |     |
 |     +--- bar.o (containing bar.c's stuff)
 |     |
 |     +--- bar.ko (containing bar.o)
 |
 +--- kernel-module.ko (containing only foo.o)
```

I'm hoping that building one module per directory is not a fundamental assumption of Kbuild's design. Shipping several modules sounds like a lot of mess for no gain.

This is my root `Makefile`:

```
KERNEL_DIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

obj-m += kernel-module.o
obj-m += subdir/
kernel-module-objs += foo.o

all:
    make -C ${KERNEL_DIR} M=$$PWD
modules:
    make -C ${KERNEL_DIR} M=$$PWD $@
clean:
    make -C ${KERNEL_DIR} M=$$PWD $@
```

This is `subdir/Makefile`:

```
obj-m += bar.o
```

This is `foo.c`:

```
int external_function(void);

int test(void)
{
    return external_function();
}
```

And this is `subdir/bar.c`:

```
int external_function(void)
{
    return 4;
}
```

`make` (in the root directory) spits the following warning:

```
WARNING: "external_function" [(...)/kernel-module.ko] undefined!
```

And my attempts to insert `kernel-module.ko` are refused:

```
$ sudo insmod kernel-module.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module kernel-module.ko: Unknown symbol in module
$ dmesg | tail -1
[11688.540153] kernel_module: Unknown symbol external_function (err 0)
```

How do I tell Kbuild that `subdir/bar.o` is supposed to be part of `kernel-module.ko` and not its own module?

Comment: The advice in that documentation is bad, or at least unclear. Your source files are `foo.c`, `bar.c` and `bar.h`; where are they? Where do you want the object files `foo.o` and `bar.o`, in the top directory or `subdir/` or `build/` or somewhere else? Likewise, where do you want the final product `outside.ko`?

Comment: @Beta: Thanks for your questions. I found a solution while editing. But just for completeness sake, here are your answers: `foo.c` is in the root directory, `bar.c` belongs to `subdir/`. Where the generated files end up is not really within the scope of this question; I'm more concerned about their contents. I would honestly wish they would end up in `build/`, but see my edits for an acceptable outcome.

Comment: @Beta: Also: regarding `bar.h`, I ended up removing it from the question because it was unnecesary. The point is, foo can see bar's declarations, but not its definitions.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to append bar's object file to the kernel module's object listing. The problem with this code:

```
obj-m += kernel-module.o
obj-m += subdir/
kernel-module-objs += foo.o
```

Is that it's telling Kbuild to descend to `subdir/`, but it's not telling it to include the results of that in `kernel-module`.

This would fix that:

```
obj-m += kernel-module.o
obj-m += subdir/
kernel-module-objs += foo.o subdir/bar.o
```

However, I don't like this solution at all because it breaks the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle: It means `bar.o` has to be named twice; one in `/Makefile` and the other one in `/subdir/Makefile`.

Also, this solution doesn't prevent Kbuild from creating the redundant `subdir/bar.ko` module.

Finally, certain [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt) states that it is "NOT recommended practice" for some completely unstated reason.

So this solution is pretty bad. I don't think I will stick to it.

---

Another solution (which branches from the previous one) is to just delete `subdir/Makefile` and, within the root Makefile, instead of this:

```
obj-m += kernel-module.o
obj-m += subdir/
kernel-module-objs += foo.o
```

do this:

```
obj-m += kernel-module.o
kernel-module-objs += foo.o subdir/bar.o
```

This fixes the DRY issue and prevents `subdir/bar.ko` from being generated but still suffers from discouraged practice.

I will stick to this solution in the meantime, but since neither of them is ideal, I guess I'll leave the question open for a while.

Comment: I agree that such practice should be discouraged.

Comment: @0andriy whyyy?

Comment: have you find out a better solution?

Comment: @photonic.bean No. However, I've never found anything even remotely resembling a problem with the second solution.

Comment: I am now convinced that the practice of one Makefile per directory is pointless legacy fat and should be avoided: http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf